# MongoDB with mongoose: is it possible to prioritize commands?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection-pooling

I'm using MongoDB with mongoose on Node.JS to build a REST server.

I'm inserting lot of records and at the same time the server attends queries from the clients.
I'd like to setup a 20 connections pool but keep 5 connections to attend clients. So, 15 connections to insert and 5 to query.

Is it possible to make it?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but a pattern that gets used a lot in this circumstance is to have two actual databases with replication.  This introduces a bit of a delay between insert and read, but is more scalable long term.  Alternatively, you could create two different db users with different rights, and then create connections for each. Mongoose, by default, pools when all the connection params are the same.

Comment: The same happens with the official driver or it's something about mongoose?